# For a water pipe connecting game, how to properly check all 4 adjacent grids without backflow or using Update()/LateUpdate()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The game I'm trying to code is a pipe connecting game where there are 4 water sources (top left, bottom left, top right, and bottom right) and the goal is to connect them to ~ 11 buildings all situated on the topmost row of the grid.

The grid I set up is a 21 by 9 list of 32x32px squares that each hold a reference to a null "Pipe" class. I also made a water source (basically "hasWater = true") at Grid<0> for testing purposes.

Here's how I'm doing the outlet flagging of my Pipe class:

```
`  public class Pipe {

   bool pipehasTop; // Top outlet flag
   bool pipehasRight; // Right outlet flag
   bool pipehasBottom; // Bottom outlet flag
   bool pipehasLeft; // Left outlet flag
   bool hasWater; // To determine pipe color and whether it can spread to other pipes
   bool outletCount; // No. of outlets (I pipe has 2, T pipe has 3, etc)
   bool connectedCount; // No. of outlets connected to adjacent grid's outlet
   }
```

Rotation is done separately whereby when I press the middle-mouse, it will change the flags according to their pipe type (which works as intended)

The instantiated grid squares by default are null when I haven't placed a pipe. The system currently in place is that I will press a hotkey to select a pipe, rotate it if needed, then place the pipe onto the grid by clicking on it, turning the null reference into the selected pipe variant. Hence almost everywhere in my code I am required to put a "if != null" for pipes :(

I'm currently using a for loop to loop through each grid square horizontally first then vertically - logic being to check each adjacent grid for matching flags and whether that adjacent grid "hasWater", if all returns true then the grid-in-question will now have water.

```
    for(int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
            int gridIndex = (y*columns) + x; // Horizontal 0, 1, 2, etc
                if(y > 0 && Grid[gridIndex - columns].pipe != null)
                    if(Grid[gridIndex - columns].pipe.pipehasBottom == true // Check if above grid has bottom flag
                      && Grid[gridIndex].pipe.pipehasTop == true // Check if current grid has top flag
                      && Grid[gridIndex - columns].pipe.hasWater == true) { // Check if above grid has water
                      Grid[gridIndex].pipe.hasWater == true;
                      }
            }
    }
```

And I repeat that for the other 3 adjacent tiles of right, bottom, and left.

At first I encountered a "ghost" water pipe issue whereby when the pipe chain was disconnected, the detached pipes would check against the adjacent grid that still has water and regain the water back, then the whole chain does then each set of 2 or more detached pipes will become self-sustaining, UNLESS I remove the pipes until it is by itself, then only will it have no water grids to check against, thus becoming void of water.

**I did a mini fix by running a method before the checking loop to turn ALL pipe.hasWater to false THEN running the adjacent check**

However, because of the horizontal nature of the checking loop I'm stuck with, when everything is false and it checks row by row, placing a new pipe on top a grid that has water will NOT check it and placing a new pipe to the left of a grid that has water will also NOT check it. I can't remove the "turn all water to false" method because it will cause the "ghost water pipe" issue again.

[image]

I have been trying for a few days to find a workaround and this was the best I could come up with... and most of the pipe checking logic are under **Update() and LateUpdate()...** when I don't do that it would either check halfway or just break at random places.

I just can't seem to find a balanced solution for this seemingly simple check.

Thank you for reading and please help me understand this dynamic pipe checking logic! I will continue to find a solution.

Comment: You should simulate separately, not as part of the Update of the individual tiles, but as part of an update of some sort of (level-)global grid object.  Then use double-buffering on this simulator to prevent the kind of issues you are seeing -- i.e. compute the next grid in a separate array from the current grid, then swap when you are done.

Comment: I was afraid to try a new search algorithm as I've written so much already, but it seems like doing the separate array search would be better for the way this grid is set up since it requires a 4-way grid-check. What are the methods I can still keep as Update()? Or should the relevant code be ran only upon detection of the grid changing via adding pipes or nullifying pipes? A few other methods running under update are 1. Is pipe hasWater ? Color.blue : Color.white 2. Is Grid[0] != null && hasLeft? this.hasWater = true (To constantly keep this as water source)

Comment: It's a matter of balance, but I would generally strive to separate the simulation (where water is and how it moves) from the presentation (sprites, colors, animations).  Imagine you wanted to have a separate mode where you simulate very fast without drawing anything; indeed, without even needing Unity framework. Make that mode possible and you will achieve a good design. Then later you might even be able to use that mode in your game, say to predict the consequences of a move. Read about [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) -- this is very similar.

Comment: Also, you might be delighted how simple your game logic becomes when you really nail the design. You will feel a sense of relief as your code improves, as gnarly little details you had to keep in your mind are freed leaving more space to think. Refactoring is not something to fear or avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably need is a better algorithm for checking the connectivity of pipes that have water.  My first reaction is to make an algorithm that basically follows the flow of water from a source and fills in each pipe's `hasWater` flag.  You would want to run this every time a tile is removed / added to properly recompute if it has water.  The one I'll pseudocode here is a [breadth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

In pseudocode:

```
reset all hasWater flags to false

//Use a queue object to place the pipes that we are declaring as having water
//but that we still need to check if they have any neighbors that will get water
var pipesWithWaterToProcess = new Queue();

//seed the queue with pipes that connect to a water source (ie. one of the sources in the corners)
foreach waterSource in waterSources
    if exists an adjacent pipe that has an outlet that connects to the water source
        if pipe does not have water already
            add pipe to pipesWithWaterToProcess queue
            flip the has water flag to true
        end 
    end
end

while pipesWithWaterToProcess queue has items
    var currentPipe = pipesWithWaterToProcess.dequeue()
    for each adjoining tile to the currentPipe
        if tile has pipe (newPipe) and newPipe connects to currentPipe
            if newPipe does not have water
                flip the hasWater flag
                add newPipe to the pipesWithWaterToProcess queue
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Assume you have a map like this:

```
S-A-B-D-
  |   |
  C-
  |
```

(the lines are connections and S is the water source).

This way what ends up happening is that you start at a water source and add pipe A to the queue.  Then you look at the queue and see that there are things to process.  So you take A out and look at it's neighbors.  If B and C are connected to A, you declare that B and C have water and add them to the queue (because now you need to check all their neighbors).  Then you do B.  B adds D.  Then you do C, but there aren't any pipes connected to C.  Then you do D, which also adds no pipes.  Then you are done and everything that is connected will show as having water.

Comment: Ah... I must have tried to derive from the traditional approach of pipe checking that was meant for preset grid pipes that cannot be removed once instantiated, but only rotated. Your explanation is very clear and I will definitely give this a go. Will keep you posted on my results, thanks!

Comment: I'm having a slight problem with the iteration of the Dequeueing of my indexed gameobject. The Grid gameobject being Enqueued holds a reference to its list like this: GridSlots[slotIndex]. It seems that I cannot retrieve that object with all its properties to Dequeue and run the check. I've tried casting the DQ object to a GameObject[] and List<GameObject> but always returns an error "InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type." The source-adjacent tile check works but once I enqueue that to check for the tile-adjacent check, it pops that error.

Comment: I will try positional checking instead of list index checking.